# Attemping AWS 'mobiletargeting' call but getting error - Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'ses'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, integration

Following on from my issue here : [How to generate the session token for AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302956/how-to-generate-the-session-token-for-aws)

I can now connect to the AWS API but am getting this error:

```
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

**{"message":"Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'ses'. "}**

The frustrating thing is, like in my first issue, the code works 100% of the time in Postman. Here is the code that Postman generates, which I have copied into C# and added the signature from the previous question:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
{MaxTimeout = -1,};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("/v1/email/identities/someone@awebsite.com", Method.Get);

var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var dateTimeStamp = date.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
request.AddHeader("X-Amz-Date", dateTimeStamp);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", 
    "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=[ourCredintialHere]/20230527/us-east-1/mobiletargeting/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=" + signature);
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I've tried changing "mobiletargeting" to "ses" but that doesn't work either, and there seems to be very little I can find on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API call is working in Postman but not in your C# code, the problem is likely with how the C# code is handling the signing of the AWS API request.

When you are using Postman, it is possible that you are making use of AWS Signature authorization, which automatically takes care of signing the request correctly. This includes using the correct scope for the AWS credentials, which is likely why you are not encountering the same error when using Postman.

In your C# code, you are manually constructing the AWS Signature and it appears there may be an issue with how the scope of the AWS credentials is being specified. You need to ensure that the service and region in the scope of the AWS credentials match the service and region that you are trying to access with your API call.

In your signing code (from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345287/6309)), there are two lines where the service name is hardcoded as "`execute-api`". This could be the root of your issue.

In the `CreateSignature` method, replace this line:

```cs
byte[] kService = HmacSha256("execute-api", kRegion);
```

with:

```cs
byte[] kService = HmacSha256("ses", kRegion);
```

And in the `Sign` method, replace:

```cs
string credentialScope = $"{dateStamp}/{region}/execute-api/aws4_request";
```

with:

```cs
string credentialScope = $"{dateStamp}/{region}/ses/aws4_request";
```

"`ses`" is the service name for the Simple Email Service.
Your `credentialScope` and `kService` should now be correctly configured for SES.

This "fix" is just for testing for your current issue. If you want to make the code more generic, to be used with any AWS service, you might want to consider passing the service name as a parameter to the `Initialize` and `Sign` methods, and use it in `credentialScope` and `kService` instead of hardcoding it.

---

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. 
Consult the service documentation for details.
```

This error message suggests that the signature calculated by AWS does not match the signature you provided in the request.

Regarding your question about `AccessKeyId` being different, the `sessionTokenResponse.Credentials` object should contain temporary security credentials that include an access key ID, a secret access key, and a session token. The `AccessKeyId` in this object will be different from your long-term access key ID if you are assuming a role or retrieving temporary credentials using the Security Token Service. If you are signing your request with temporary security credentials, you should be using the access key ID, secret access key, and session token from the `sessionTokenResponse.Credentials` object.

Make sure you are using the correct access key ID and secret access key to create the signing key and the signature. If you are using temporary security credentials, make sure you are also including the session token in your request.

When you call AWS STS (Security Token Service) to assume a role or to get temporary credentials, it returns a response with temporary security credentials. These temporary credentials include an access key ID, a secret access key, and a session token, which are different from your original long-term credentials. The temporary credentials are what you should use for signing the request.

If you use these temporary credentials to sign your request, you need to make sure to include the session token in your request headers (typically `x-amz-security-token`). If you do not include the session token or if you use the wrong access key ID or secret access key to sign your request, AWS will not be able to match the signature you provided to the one it calculates, resulting in the "`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.`" error.

Do check for:

- **Incorrect Signing Key**: When signing a request, AWS uses a derived signing key, which is generated from your secret access key. If you're not using the correct secret access key, the derived signing key and the resulting signature will be incorrect.
- **Incorrect String to Sign**: The signature is calculated from a string that includes the request method, the canonical URI, the canonical query string, the canonical headers, the signed headers, and the hashed payload. If any of these components are not being formatted or included correctly in your string to sign, the resulting signature will not match the one calculated by AWS.
- **Incorrect Date**: AWS signatures include the date and time of the request to protect against replay attacks. If the date you're using to calculate the signature is different from the date in your request, the signatures will not match. Make sure you're using the same date in your `x-amz-date` header, your credential scope, and your string to sign.

---

> I think the problem is in the `Sign(HttpRequestMessage request, string sessionToken)` function, as I'm getting the "The format of value ... is invalid" error on `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);` even though it looks identical to what is in the Postman header.

The error message "The format of value ... is invalid" suggests that the value you are trying to add to the "`Authorization`" header in the `HttpRequestMessage` does not meet the formatting requirements for an HTTP header value.

HTTP header values must conform to certain rules defined in the HTTP/1.1 specification. For example, they must not contain control characters, including newline or carriage return characters.
If the value you are trying to add to the "`Authorization`" header contains any such characters, you would see an error like the one you are encountering.

If the value of the "`Authorization`" header appears to be identical in Postman and your C# code, but the request is only failing in the C# code, there may be some invisible control characters in the value that are not being displayed (or a newline you are not aware of). You could try printing the "`Authorization`" header value to the console or a log file to check for any hidden control characters. Always use delimiters when doing a debug printing (`Console.WriteLine($"{variableName} = '{variableValue}'");`).

To compare the requests being made by Postman and your C# code, you can look at the following components of the requests:

1. The URL: Make sure the URLs are identical, including any query parameters.
2. The HTTP method: Make sure the HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc.) are the same.
3. The headers: Check that all the headers in the Postman request are also in the C# request and have the same values. Pay special attention to the "`Authorization`", "`x-amz-date`", and "`x-amz-security-token`" headers.
4. The body: If the request has a body, make sure it is the same in both the Postman and C# requests.

In Postman, you can see all these details in the "`Headers`" and "`Body`" tabs. You can also use Postman's code generation feature to generate the equivalent C# code for your request, which can help you see how Postman is constructing the request.

In your C# code, you can print the URL, method, headers, and body of the `HttpRequestMessage` to the console or a log file before sending the request to compare with the Postman request.

Comment: Hi @VonC. Thanks again for your help. I did have mobiletargeting instead of execute-api as I thought that was the issue, but making it ses has changed the error message ...! (One step forward, one back). I now get this at the same point -- "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
And idea on this one?

Comment: I think it might be something to do with this line - var temporaryCredentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
  When I break on it, and inspect, the AccessKeyId is something completely different to what I have when I call the signer. Where is this value coming from?

Comment: @RodneyEllis OK, I have updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Sign(HttpRequestMessage request, string sessionToken) function as I'm getting the "The format of value ... is invalid" error on "request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);" even though it looks identical to what is in the Postman header. 
Is there a way I can pay you for a quick zoom/teams consulation to go through the code together? I've spent over a day on this and am at a loss.

Comment: @RodneyEllis The most I can do is for you to add a comment here, [which should trigger the chat invitation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372349/6309): the back and forth will be more interactive in a chat session.

Comment: @RodneyEllis In the meantime, I have edited the answer with a few debugging suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance VonC, I really appreciate it. But I had most of your debugging suggestions done already, and have gone through your walkthroughs twice today, and am no closer. 
Given the time I've spent on this, I'm talking to my manager at the business I consult to about finding a different platform. It shouldn't be this hard, so I fear AWS might've lost a client.

Comment: @RodneyEllis OK, let me know of your conclusions after your talk.

Comment: I think we're moving to SendGrid or MailGun as their APIs are a lot simpler. Already got both working in their sandboxes, now up to my boss to choose which one she wants to go with.